# Outlook 2016 crashes upon startup - Windows 7 after recent update.

Tags: windows-7, windows

I installed Office Pro 2016 and I just had a software update yesterday and since then my Outlook 2016 keeps crashing upon startup.  I don't have Macaffey on my computer.  I am running Windows 7.  It ran fine until the automatic update yesterday.

Comment: What @Fiasco Labs said appears to be true, Starting Outlook in safe mode and Disabling automatic downloads of pictures in outlooks Trust Center might be a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the CTRL key when you start Outlook. Start it in SAFE mode.

Known issue, Microsoft has a Webfont/Openfont vulnerability hole in Outlook and bodged the patch to make it go away.

If the safe mode workaround doesn't do it till Microsoft patches the patch, you can try uninstalling KB3097877